# Numpy adding values to diagonals

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I wish to create an `NxN` `numpy` array where only everything above the main diagonal is filled. 
The way it is filled is that the main diagonal (`k=0`) is filled with `gamma**0`, the `k=1` diagonal is filled with `gamma**1`, the `k=2` diagonal is filled with `gamma**2` etc...

```
gamma = 0.9
dim = 4

M = np.zeros((dim,dim))
for i in range(dim)[::-1]:   
    M += np.diagflat([gamma**(dim-i-1)]*(i+1),dim-i-1) 

print(M)
```

This correctly gives

```
array([[ 1.   ,  0.9  ,  0.81 ,  0.729],
       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.9  ,  0.81 ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.9  ],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```

I wanted to ask if there were any more simpler or elegant ways of handling this or something different. I will be handling with multidimensial arrays frequently and I wanted to be inspired by different tools and approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to create the upper triangular indices with [`np.triu_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) and then use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to assign values to those positions:

```
M = np.zeros((dim,dim))

rowidx, colidx = np.triu_indices(dim)
# the diagonal offset can be calculated by subtracting the row index from column index
M[rowidx, colidx] = gamma ** (colidx - rowidx) 

M
#array([[ 1.   ,  0.9  ,  0.81 ,  0.729],
#       [ 0.   ,  1.   ,  0.9  ,  0.81 ],
#       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ,  0.9  ],
#       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ]])
```